# Make UITableViewCell into a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView, and in the `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, I want to be able to access the frame that the selected cell is in.  Here is what I was trying:

```
UIView *cell = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
```

`UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)indexPath;`

I want to be able to access the view that the selected cell is in.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, use:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

than you can access all the info on cell as you would any other `UIView`

ie. `cell.frame`, `cell.bound`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the cell directly isn’t necessary—yes, you can get the cell and its frame via `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but you’d then have to subtract the content offset of the UIScrollView (which UITableView subclasses from) to get the cell’s actual position within the boundaries of the table view. The best approach for this is the UITableView method `-rectForRowAtIndexPath:`.